# PHP dropdown if value is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I currently have a block of jQuery that I have included this seems to work fine on the comps I have tested `OSX, XP` however on mobile devices and another computers I have had people to test its still going to the old URL however I do suspect it could be a cache issue but is there a way to develop a PHP fall back?

What I would like to do if the `prop2` value is selected I would like to change the form action url almost onclick like the jQuery does.

**HTML:**

```
<form action='bookingurl' method='get'>
     <label for='channel_code' class="caption">Select property </label>
          <select id='channel_code' name='id'> 
            <option value='prop1'>Prop 1</option>              
            <option value='prop2'>Prop 2</option>
          </select> 
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#channel_code').change(function(){

        if(jQuery('#channel_code').val() == 'prop2'){

             window.location.href = 'https://hotels.cloudbeds.com/reservation/url';

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: `if($('#channel_code option:selected').val() == 'prop2'){` try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#channel_code').change(function() {

    if ($('#channel_code option:selected').val() == 'prop2') {
alert("go to")
      //window.location.href = 'https://hotels.cloudbeds.com/reservation/url';

    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='bookingurl' method='get'>
  <label for='channel_code' class="caption">Select property</label>
  <select id='channel_code' name='id'>
    <option value='prop1'>Prop 1</option>
    <option value='prop2'>Prop 2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Specify the selector as:

`$('#channel_code option:selected').val()`//meaning option selected value

Comment: Thanks,  However its still going to the old url on mobile mmm

Comment: that is a different problem that the current one then :)